# The parameter 'firebaseFirestore' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null' in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I declared two variables of type `FirebaseFirestore` and `FireBaseAuth`, and now i am facing an error of null safety. I am using a constructor in my class, and passing them as paraeters, with getting an error of -
`The parameter 'firebaseFirestore' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null' in flutter` and  `The parameter 'firebaseAuth' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null' in flutter`.

The code part consisting of my problem is -

```
import 'package:flutter_instagram_clone_final/repositories/repositories.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;

class AuthRepository extends BaseAuthRepository {

  final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore;
  final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  AuthRepository({
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore,
    auth.FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth,
  })  : _firebaseFirestore = firebaseFirestore ?? FirebaseFirestore.instance,
        _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

Then I tried to initialize it with instance, like -

```
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance,
```

But it is giving me an error that - `The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To guarantee that you never see a null parameter with a non-nullable
> type, the type checker requires all optional parameters to either have
> a nullable type or a default value.

[Understanding null safety | Dart](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters)

You need to make `firebaseFirestore` and `firebaseAuth` nullable since they are optional and their default values are not constant.

You can do that by adding `?` right after the type.

Like this:

```dart
    FirebaseFirestore? firebaseFirestore,
    auth.FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth,
```

So your constructor can be updated to this:

```dart
    AuthRepository({
        FirebaseFirestore? firebaseFirestore,
        auth.FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth,
      })  : _firebaseFirestore = firebaseFirestore ?? FirebaseFirestore.instance,
            _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

Comment: Thanks bro. So generous and kind of you for helping me out on this small error.