# null safety error when creating Flutter classes and widgets

Tags: flutter, class, dart, widget, dart-null-safety

I am learning Flutter / Dart and when doing the exercise in this [video](https://youtu.be/8m9Zcv2SWh0?list=PL6PxPH2IZvJroeV7Y5m_qdcGnGtHnTyQb) I have encountered an error that from what I understand is due to the null-safety feature and because the example is from a previous version, the problem appears .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OurImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String pathImage;
  final double widthImage;
  final double heightImage;
  OurImage({this.pathImage, this.heightImage, this.widthImage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final photo = Container(
      width: this.widthImage,
      height: this.heightImage,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(this.pathImage), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
    );

    return photo;
  }
}
```

> The parameter 'pathImage' can't have a value of 'null' because of its
> type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. Try adding either an
> explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

When reading these errors [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66695339/the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-string-w), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560461/the-parameter-cant-have-a-value-of-null-because-of-its-type-in-dart), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67790620/the-parameter-firebasefirestore-cant-have-a-value-of-null-because-of-its-ty) about null-safety I thought about correcting the error that appears to me by adding "?" and "!" to my code, with which I validate that the errors no longer appear.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OurImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? pathImage; //change here
  final double? widthImage; //change here
  final double? heightImage; //change here
  OurImage({this.pathImage, this.heightImage, this.widthImage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final photo = Container(
      width: this.widthImage,
      height: this.heightImage,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(this.pathImage!), fit: BoxFit.cover)), //change here
    );

    return photo;
  }
}
```

**Is the way I have obtained to fix it correct? How should I create the variables of the OurImage class so that it does not generate this error?**

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely right to follow on-screen suggestions to fix errors. Take a look into the null safety guide for understanding it better and working with it.

Comment: Make `widthImage` and `heightImage` nullable looks okay.  Making `pathImage` nullable looks wrong since you later *unconditionally* use `pathImage!`, which asserts that `pathImage` is *not* `null`.  That would result in a runtime crash if `pathImage` was not set.  A more appropriate fix would be: A. make `pathImage` non-nullable and make it a `required` argument to the constructor; B. check if `pathImage` is `null` and *conditionally* use `AssetImage`; C. make `pathImage` non-nullable and initialize it to some default, non-`null` value if not provided as a constructor argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make anything nullable but you should consider it in your whole code and  every place that item is used. you need to provide a replaceable behavior for when the value is null (because that's possible due to nullablity)

for example for nullable attributes you should provide a default value like (1) or handle it in usages like (2)

*(1)*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OurImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? pathImage; //change here
  final double? widthImage; //change here
  final double? heightImage; //change here
  OurImage({this.pathImage = 'default image path', this.heightImage = 100, this.widthImage = 100});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final photo = Container(
      width: this.widthImage,
      height: this.heightImage,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(this.pathImage), fit: BoxFit.cover)), //change here
    );

    return photo;
  }
}
```

*(2)*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OurImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? pathImage; //change here
  final double? widthImage; //change here
  final double? heightImage; //change here
  OurImage({this.pathImage, this.heightImage, this.widthImage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final photo = Container(
      width: this.widthImage ?? 100,
      height: this.heightImage ?? 100,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(this.pathImage ?? 'default image path'), fit: BoxFit.cover)), //change here
    );

    return photo;
  }
}
```